# Writing a MonadRandom instance for MWC (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, monads

I want to be able to use the [MWC random number generator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mwc-random-0.13.2.0/docs/System-Random-MWC.html) with random-fu, and so need to implement an instance of `MonadRandom`. My attempt is to consider a `Reader (Gen (PrimState m)) v` a `MonadRandom v`. However, the following fails:

```
$(monadRandom [d|
  instance (PrimMonad m) => MonadRandom (Reader (MWC.Gen (PrimState m))) where
    getRandomWord16 = ask >>= MWC.uniform
    getRandomWord32 = ask >>= MWC.uniform
    getRandomWord64 = ask >>= MWC.uniform
  |])
```

with the error:

```
Illegal type synonym family application in instance:
  Reader (MWC.Gen (PrimState m_ahwD))
In the instance declaration for
  ‘MonadRandom (Reader (MWC.Gen (PrimState m_ahwD)))’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is exactly what the compiler has told you it is: you can't have type family applications in an instance. The easiest way to get rid of the type family in the instance *head* is to just place it into the *context*: `instance (PrimMonad m, s ~ PrimState m) => MonadRandom (Reader (MWC.Gen s))` (assuming the actual code is otherwise correct and there are no other issues, of course). Another solution is replace `PrimState m` with what it represents, namely once instance for `IO` and one for `ST s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on what the other contributors have already said

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Random
import Data.Random.Source
import qualified System.Random.MWC as MWC
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Primitive

$(monadRandom [d|
  instance (PrimMonad m, s ~ PrimState m) => MonadRandom (ReaderT (MWC.Gen s) m) where
    getRandomWord16 = ask >>= lift . MWC.uniform
    getRandomWord32 = ask >>= lift . MWC.uniform
    getRandomWord64 = ask >>= lift . MWC.uniform
  |])

testUniform :: MonadRandom m => Int -> m [Double]
testUniform n = replicateM (fromIntegral n) (sample stdUniform)

n :: Int
n = 10^7

main :: IO ()
main = do
    seed <- MWC.create
    xs <- runReaderT (testUniform n) seed
    print (sum xs / fromIntegral n)
```

but it doesn't perform very well

```
./RandomFuMWC +RTS -s
0.5000432391067587
   3,286,220,896 bytes allocated in the heap
   2,427,475,880 bytes copied during GC
     600,186,048 bytes maximum residency (12 sample(s))
     100,510,656 bytes maximum slop
            1249 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      5942 colls,     0 par    1.06s    1.13s     0.0002s    0.0013s
  Gen  1        12 colls,     0 par    0.82s    1.23s     0.1024s    0.5787s

  INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
  MUT     time    1.47s  (  1.39s elapsed)
  GC      time    1.87s  (  2.36s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.01s  (  0.09s elapsed)
  Total   time    3.35s  (  3.84s elapsed)

  %GC     time      56.0%  (61.3% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,242,365,923 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  44.0% of total user, 38.3% of total elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted was in fact:

```
(ReaderT (MWC.Gen (PrimState m)) m)
```

You'll likely also need to replace `MWC.uniform` with

```
lift . MWC.uniform
```

Comment: I think you meant (ReaderT (MWC.Gen s) m)?

Comment: My mistake: I was conflating the two answers.